# Displaying records in an unrelated subform access 2010

Tags: ms-access, records, subform

I'm in a pickle. This is probably quite easy but I just cannot figure it out.

2 Tables with columns:

```
tbl_indicators | tbl_targets
ind_id         | id
ind_name       | ind_id
               | year
               | comment1
               | comment2
```

I have got an unrelated subform on a form. On the subform I have 3 textboxes; tbl_indicators.ind_name, tbl_targets.comment1, tbl_targets.comment2. Users need to be able to edit the comments. The subform should contain all the names from tbl_indicators and linked to each name the comment textboxes. So for example, if tbl_indicators got 10 names, the subform should view 10 records. How can I do this?

Comment: How? Do they all have the same ind_id? What do you mean unrelated?

Comment: Unrelated from the main form it resides on I mean. Usually when one uses a subform it's to display records depending on the selection on the main form right? Correct me if I'm wrong. The ind_id in tbl_targets is a reference to tbl_indicators.ind_id.

Comment: So why do you not wish to use ind_id to determine the records in tbl_targets subform? As it stands, it does not seem to make sense, after all if they are unrelated, why not just select top 10 from tbl_targets?

Comment: I do not wish to display all the information on the subform, just the ind_name field from tbl_indicators with the comment1 and comment2 fields from tbl_targets. I've made a sample database where I've tried it. In this sample the tbl_targets has one record with ind_id 2. So what I want is the subform to display all the names from tbl_indicators where only the name with ind_id = 2 will have the comment1 and comment2 fields showing their values and the comment fields are empty. Hope this makes sense. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3121767/test.zip

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not just do this in the conventional way with the main form bound to tbl_indicators and the subform bound to tbl_targets and the link master and child fields set to ind_id?

Comment: Forgot to mention it, but the main form already has a recordsource and is used for quite a lot of other controls. I need to put in a new tab inside the main form and could only think of putting a subform inside it to display the records.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15361/discussion-between-remou-and-tutu)

Comment: Tutu you have  accepted a solution, but if Albert's solution suits you, why do you have a separate tbl_targets? using Albert's solution, you will get two name rows if you have two rows in comments with the same ind_ID. If you do not need to have two comment rows for a name, you should not have a separate table.

Comment: Rows having the same ind_id in targets is not a problem. It will get filtered on year and I think also on a unique person number. The seperate table is because more names can be added so that's why it has a seperate table tbl_indicators.

Comment: Try it. Add a couple of rows to tbl_targets.

Comment: I did, I don't see anything out of the ordinary. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: You added two rows with the same ind_ID to targets and ran the query with a left join on target to indicators and did not see duplicate names, is that correct? If you cannot see that you have two rows with the same name, or if that is not a problem for you, then that is fine. I would not like to present my users with a form that looked like it had multiple duplicate names.

Comment: I did see the duplicates, but that is where the column year gets in. The main form has a field that reflects the year selected by the user, so I'd like to filter the records by year which I'm now struggling with. It seems it will only display the records with the year while I want it to display all the names with the textboxes filled in with the selected year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this sub form is not a classic "child" table of the parent. However, this sub form is based on the above need displaying ing_name.

The simple solution then is to build a query that left joins in the tbl_indiciator column of in_name.

So just build a query like this:

[image]
The above is a left join query since it may be possible that there no corresponding tbl_indicators record.

You continues sub form will thus look like this:

[image]

Comment: From the discussion, I find that there can be more than one comment line. The result of the discussion was a subform with a button to open the related comments.

Comment: Where is there any mention of a button? From comments the poster stated they want to edit the comments - nothing about a button or launching a seperate form here.

Comment: The discussion in chat (last comments line) involved sample databases and revealed that the comments table (tbl_target) has more than one entry per name - the comments table has a year field, so the join is not one-to-one. Unfortunately, I had not had time to transfer the information from chat to here at the time of your post.

Comment: I just figured it out myself about 10 minutes ago that I had to use a left outer join. But this post describes exactly what I wanted so I will mark albert D as answer. Remou I appreciate your effort but unfortunately I can't mark 2 answers, I will give your post +1. Thank you!

Comment: One question, when I fill in a comment, the row gets added to tbl_targets. When both comments are removed the line stays there, I'd like the whole row to be removed from tbl_targets when it has no comments. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In most cases, the user can just click on the reocrd selector, and hit the delete key to delete that row (reocrd). So, I think the idea here is either you have some check for the comments (required) and then users will have to delete the reocrd (or enter somthing). I cannot say I recommed an automatic delete of a row based on no comments having been entered - I think this is more of a UI question then that of the actual fact of deleting such a row in a table. - if you must, then I would consider asking this as a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the discussion was a form along these lines. The main form has a subform for names, and a button to open a small form form the comments that are associated with each name. A name can have no comments or more than one comment. The button can be a macro or VBA:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName",,,"[ind_id]=" & [ind_id]
```

[image: Form/subform line button]